# Laravel: store log of all changes for model?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design

I struggle with following problem.

It is easy to save `diff` of changes for Eloquent model when it is single column in database, but when changed data is stored in another table it is hard to do.

Example:

```
table users
    id primary key
    first_name text <- when it is changed we write this to log

user_roles
    id_user foreign key to users.id
    id_role foreign key to roles.id
```

And there can be a lot of foreign tables.

What should I do? Describe all these fields and on every update verify data in these tables `before` and `after` update?

Comment: I guess this is what you need https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events

Comment: There is problem with foreign relations (not foreign keys)

Comment: make a event that listens to changes on the User model. For example every time it is doing 'updating' that event triggers and you can do your action in a single file. Since laravel 5.4 you can add eloquent listeners directly on . your model.

Comment: But how should I verify what data has changed?